# JTextPane Filling Applet Box

Tags: swing, applet, jtextpane

I am just starting with applets so I am not to good.  I recently tried using this code:

```
public class AppletTest extends JApplet{    
  public void init(){
    try{
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){public void run(){
        setSize(500,500);
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Hello World");
        add(lbl);
        JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
        pane.setSize(200, 200);
        add(pane);
        }});
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error Occurred");
    }
  }
}
```

What I intended it to do was make a 500 by 500 applet with a text pane that is 200 by 200.  However, when I ran the program, the text pane flashed for a moment in  the correct size then proceeded to fill up the applet and cover anything else I put on in the applet.  If I expanded the applet (manipulated it by dragging the corner) the text pane would grow as well.   I tried this and got the same results with a JButton and a JPasswordField.  Is there something I am missing?  I tried setBounds(int i, int j, int k, int l) But I got the same results.  Any help?

Comment: You should read up on the use of Swing layout managers. You will find your answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change two things:

1. Explicitly set a `LayoutManager` (`FlowLayout` is simple and works fine here)
2. Call `setPreferredSize()` instead of `setSize()` for your `JTextPanel`

Here's the modified code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class AppletTest extends JApplet{    
  public void init(){
    try{
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){public void run(){
        setSize(500,500);

        // explicitly set a layout manager
        setLayout( new FlowLayout( ) );

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Hello World");
        add(lbl);
        JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();

        // use setPreferredSize, not setSize
        pane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 200 ) );

        add(pane);
        }});
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error Occurred");
    }
  }
}
```